# Passing a quoted string to ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, i want to run this command in terminal

```
pssh -h hosts -i "echo "DenyUsers $1" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd config"
```

as you can see, `"` before echo words will be broken and it will be ended by `"` before `DenyUsers $1` command.
I have changed `"` before echo and after config words and it doesn't still work like what i want.

I am newcomer in this scripting and i don't know what keywords should i put into the search engine :-)

Comment: This is really quite specifically about ssh -- in usual cases you won't [*and shouldn't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)* pass shell commands as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try
`pssh -h hosts -i "echo \"DenyUsers $1\" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd config"`
or
`pssh -h hosts -i 'echo "DenyUsers $1" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd config'`

Comment: OMG, i even don't think a \ can escape the double " in one line. This is the answer what i use because so simple. But, if you are a linux guy who understand more than a newcomer experience like me, this the right answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523422/8162936] according to the more explanation [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523295/8162936]

Comment: @NickyPuff, perhaps you were thinking about single quotes -- it's those in which a backslash is literal.

Answer (score 6):

Doing this in a manner that is safe **even if you don't trust your input** is a bit more involved.

Use `printf %q` to generate an `eval`-safe version of your data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- Requires an extension not available in /bin/sh

# printf %q is also available on ksh, but there you would write:
#   echo_str=$(printf 'DenyUsers %q' "$1")
#   cmd=$(printf '%q ' printf '%s\n' "$echo_str")
# as the ksh version doesn't have -v, but optimizes away the subshell instead.

printf -v echo_str 'DenyUsers %q' "$1"
printf -v cmd '%q ' printf '%s\n' "$echo_str"
pssh -h hosts -i "$cmd >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd config"
```

Note that `printf` is used instead of `echo` for greater predictability; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the source of `$1` can be trusted, then you can simply *escape* the inner double quotes with `\`:

```
pssh -h hosts -i "echo \"DenyUsers $1\" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd config"
```

---

The drawback to the approach above is what happens if the `$1` expands to something *malicious*, for example, to `$(rm -fr *)`. Then, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will end up containing:

```
echo "DenyUsers $(rm -fr *)"
```

which will run `rm -fr *` when executed.

For this reason, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523422/8012646) for a safer solution based on `printf %q`.

Comment: This is safe only if you trust the source of that `$1` -- if it's `$(rm -rf .)`, f/e, then that's going to be run on all your machines; and if it's a DenyUsers entry, I wouldn't be surprised to see this script used to programmatically automate prevent attempted logins from names associated with doing evil. Much safer to escape the value with `printf %q`